# Using jsonb (PostgreSQL), how do I retrieve items with a certain value that's saved as an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to find all recipes in a certain category, where the key/value data is recorded in a PostgreSQL's jsonb column (and the value is saved as an array).

For example, say I have "data" as my jsonb column in the "recipes" table, and I have three entries like so:

```
"Recipe 1" contains a "data" with key/value of: "category_ids"=>[123, 4059]
"Recipe 2" contains a "data" with key/value of: "category_ids"=>[405, 543]
"Recipe 3" contains a "data" with key/value of: "category_ids"=>[567, 982]
```

I want to retrieve only items that contain the "405" category id value (i.e. only Recipe 2 above)

This is what I have so far using Ruby on Rails to query the PostgreSQL database:

```
Recipe.where("(data ->> 'category_ids') LIKE '%405%'")
```

However, that retrieves both "Recipe 1" and "Recipe 2" because they both contain "405" text.

What query should I use to correctly retrieve recipes with the "405" category id only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also directly use IN along with json_array_elements:

```
Recipe.where("'405' IN (SELECT json_array_elements(data->'category_ids')::text)")
```

And if your column is a jsonb column, you can similarly do:

```
Recipe.where("'405' IN (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data->'category_ids')::text)")
```

Comment: Thanks, Ziggy. i got this error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function json_array_elements(jsonb) does not exist

My postgresql version is 9.5 (using Rails version 4.2.6). Do you know if I have to enable this feature in psql?

Comment: I think I know now :) I did this and it works:

Recipe.where("'405' IN (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data->'category_ids')::text)")

So instead of "json_array_elements", I used "jsonb_array_elements" because of the jsonb column.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

you need `ANY` function. Something like

```
select * from t where '405' = any (
  ARRAY(
    SELECT e::text FROM json_array_elements(data->'category_ids') e
  )
);
```

or

```
select * from t where '405' = any (
  ARRAY(
    SELECT e::text FROM jsonb_array_elements(data->'category_ids') e
  )
);
```

if your type is jsonb (higher than 9.3 postgres version)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1a895/1

Comment: Thanks so much cur4so :) I don't understand PostgreSQL too much so I used Ziggy's solution above that includes the Rails way of doing it. The jsonb_array_elements(data->'category_ids') is key so thank you so much. 

This was the query output that worked for me after doing the Rails command, which is very similar to yours:

SELECT \"recipes\".* FROM \"recipes\" WHERE ('405' IN (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data->'category_ids')::text))"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unnest function` available. More details can be check here :  [Postgresql Functions & Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html).