# Using JSON in postgres, how do I query a nested array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I have a few `User` records with a `details` json column that look like this:

```
User.create(details: {accounts: [{name: 'one', id: 1}, {name: 'two', id: 2}])
User.create(details: {accounts: [{name: 'three', id: 3}, {name: 'two', id: 2}])
User.create(details: {accounts: [{name: 'three', id: 3}, {name: 'four', id: 4}])
```

How do I query for all records where `id` is `2`?

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667401/postgres-json-data-type-rails-query OR here http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Using jsonb (PostgreSQL), how do I retrieve items with a certain value that's saved as an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123173/using-jsonb-postgresql-how-do-i-retrieve-items-with-a-certain-value-thats-sa) I was put on the right track.

The query to match:

```
User.where("? in (SELECT json_array_elements(details->'accounts')->>'id')", "2")
```